# Random PostScript File in my home folder

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, screenshot, postscript

Today I have installed Xubuntu 14.04 on my machine.
I set up some program and different tool.

But when I right-click on a file, in 'Open With' line I see an empty cell:

[image: screenshot here]

When I click on it appears a cross mouse pointer that I can drag on the screen. To return to default mouse I double click on window.

Then PostScript Images appear in my home folder ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jnUJ.jpg)). These images are like screenshots of the view when I clicked on the blank line.

How to solve this?
Can I delete the  blank line in 'Open With' option?

EDIT:

As suggested this is the output of `grep -r 'text/x-python' ~/.local/share/applications`:

```
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom_loader.py-8NH4XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom-2Y34XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-python-H5O7XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-%f-MEQYXX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-%f-5U2UXX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom-M739XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom-l.sh-SA27XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom-l.sh-EJT5XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-dj-py.py-VM06XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-python-VGY5XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom-KVDDYX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-ip.py-XFIWXX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-python atom_loader.py-O0W4XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-sudo reboot-FDOUXX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:text/x-python=menulibre-sublime-text-2.desktop;
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom_loader.py-6UNFYX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-%f-7ZQCYX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom-J8IFYX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-%f-MO9EYX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-ip.py-UYFVXX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom-l.sh-MR2UXX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-dj-py.py-YAR4XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-python-5XZ4XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-atom-9Y73XX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:text/x-python=userapp-python atom_loader.py-HABUXX.desktop;userapp-atom-9Y73XX.desktop;userapp-python-5XZ4XX.desktop;userapp-dj-py.py-YAR4XX.desktop;userapp-atom-l.sh-MR2UXX.desktop;userapp-ip.py-UYFVXX.desktop;userapp-%f-MO9EYX.desktop;userapp-atom-J8IFYX.desktop;userapp-%f-7ZQCYX.desktop;userapp-atom_loader.py-6UNFYX.desktop;userapp-sudo reboot-FDOUXX.desktop;userapp-python atom_loader.py-O0W4XX.desktop;userapp-ip.py-XFIWXX.desktop;userapp-atom-KVDDYX.desktop;userapp-python-VGY5XX.desktop;userapp-dj-py.py-VM06XX.desktop;userapp-atom-l.sh-EJT5XX.desktop;userapp-atom-l.sh-SA27XX.desktop;userapp-atom-M739XX.desktop;userapp-%f-5U2UXX.desktop;userapp-%f-MEQYXX.desktop;userapp-python-H5O7XX.desktop;userapp-atom-2Y34XX.desktop;userapp-atom_loader.py-8NH4XX.desktop;
/home/tree/.local/share/applications/userapp-python atom_loader.py-HABUXX.desktop:MimeType=text/x-python
```

This is the output of `mimetype dj-py.py`:

```
dj-py.py: text/x-python
```

No output for `grep -r 'text/x-python' /usr/share/applications`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r 'text/x-python' /usr/share/applications` and the output of `grep -r 'text/x-python' ~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: And please the output of `mimetype dj-py.py` and give me a ping with `@A.B.`

Comment: @A.B. I edited the question